# Problems to iterate objects in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have this method below which is responsible for bringing me an array of objects (blog).

```
public function getListaBlogsById($id) {
    $result = array();
    try {
        $statement = $this->getDb()->prepare('SELECT * FROM Blog WHERE categoria_id = :id');
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getTrace();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And I know that the array is not null. What I want to do is to iterate the objects inside the array in this way:

```
<?php foreach ($blog_category as $item): ?>
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php echo Utils::createLink('detail-post', array('id' => $item->getId())); ?>"><?php echo $item->getTitle(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    <p class="lead">
        by <a href="<?php echo Utils::createLink('detail-post', array('id' => $item->getId())); ?>"><?php echo $item->getAuthor(); ?></a>
    </p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Postado em 
        <?php $date = strtotime($item->getDate());
            $br_format = date("d/m/Y g:i A", $date);
            echo $br_format;
        ?></p>
    <hr>
    <a href="<?php echo Utils::createLink('detail-post', array('id' => $item->getId())); ?>">                
        <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="../web/img/1850_james_ancestry.JPG" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <hr>
    <p><?php echo $item->getPre(); ?></p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo Utils::createLink('detail-post', array('id' => $item->getId())); ?>">Leia mais <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But the page renders nothing.

Any light will be appreciated.

Comment: when you say nothing, what you mean? White screen? error messages?

Comment: NO errors, just a white page.

Answer (score 1):

The object that is used will have been created from strClass() and therefore does not have any get methods associated with it.

So change your script like so in order to access the properties of these objects directly rather than expecting them to have an associated `->getxxx()` method.

```
<a href="<?php echo Utils::createLink('detail-post', array('id' => $item->id)); ?>">
<?php echo $item->title; ?>
</a>
```

The actual names of the properties will depend on the column names ( and column name case) you have on the table you queried.

You may also need to change this line in your `getListaBlogsById($id)` funtion to ensure that the data is returned as an object and not an array

From

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

To

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, thank you for you assistence. But when i put $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS); I will have array of objects with his properties like get ?

Comment: Thats what you said your wanted. If you wanted an array of arrays then using `$item->getId()` would make even less sense!

Comment: It might be useful to see where `$blog_category` is actually populated as currently I am just assuming by virtue of the code you supplied, it is with the results of `getListaBlogsById($id)`

Comment: yeah, with $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS) i'm still getting white page. I cant access by get methods. `if (array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) {

    $blog_category = $dao->getListaBlogsById($_GET['id']);

}  else {
    Utils::redirect('blog');
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RiggsFolly for your help. I solve my problem making some modification as fallows:

```
public function getListaBlogsById($id) {
    try {
        $result = array();
        $blog = new Blog();
        $statement = $this->getDb()->prepare('SELECT * FROM Blog WHERE categoria_id = :id');
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
        if ($statement->execute()) {
            while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
                BlogMapper::map($blog, $row);
                $result[$blog->getId()] = $blog;
            }
        }         

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getTrace();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and

```
public static function map(Blog $blog, array $properties) {

    if (array_key_exists('id', $properties)) {
        $blog->setId($properties['id']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('blog_author', $properties)) {
        $blog->setAuthor($properties['blog_author']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('blog_article_title', $properties)) {
        $blog->setTitle($properties['blog_article_title']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('blog_date_creation', $properties)) {
        $blog->setDate($properties['blog_date_creation']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('blog_article_pre', $properties)) {
        $blog->setPre($properties['blog_article_pre']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('blog_article', $properties)) {
        $blog->setArticle($properties['blog_article']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('categoria_id', $properties)) {
        $blog->setCategoria_id($properties['categoria_id']);
    }
}
```